# Django cannot find database when using docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV WORKDIR /usr/src/app

WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install pipenv


COPY ./Pipfile* ${WORKDIR}/

RUN pipenv lock --requirements > requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . ${WORKDIR}/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: development
      POSTGRES_USER: development
      POSTGRES_DB: dev_db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  backend:
    build: .
    command: python /usr/src/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - database
```

**Django database configurations**

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'dev_db',
        'USER': 'development',
        'PASSWORD': 'development',
        'HOST': 'database',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

However, when I start docker compose, it gives the following message:

```
> Is the server running on host "database" (172.29.0.2) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Can anyone provide some guidance on why I'm getting this error? As far as I know both services are inside the same network

Comment: Is there anything in the `database` container logs about potential problems to initialize/run the database server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because when the Django instance is ready, Postgres is still starting up.

A common solution is to use a script like [wait-for](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for) to delay the execution of a command until a service is replying on a specific host/port.

Take a look at the Docker documentation about [controlling the startup order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) of multiple containers.

Comment: You're right I replace the command inside my backend service `bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/database/5432; do sleep 1; done; python /usr/src/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'` and now it is working as expected. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the hostname in the yml file. See below

```
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    hostname: database
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: development
      POSTGRES_USER: development
      POSTGRES_DB: dev_db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Comment: Hello, tried to add hostmane with no luck, django app is still unable to find the database